# HTML link is not to a valid folder...but it still works?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm having some trouble understanding a bit of HTML and was hoping that SO could help me in the process of figuring out what is going on, so that I might be able to do this myself in the future.

The markup is simple  :

```
<p>
  GET <a href="~/api/function">/api/function</a>: returns list of info from database.
</p>
```

Now, this works fully and I am trying to understand what is going on. My understanding is that this would go to root directory, find a folder called api, find a function called function and run it.

The problem is that there is no folder called api - so what could be going on here ? I can find the C# function that is actually being called to retrieve the items from the DB, but I cannot figure out how the code calling this might be structured. I have a class which extends DbContext to retrieve information, but I cannot see how this is being called and it is not on the call stack when I insert a breakpoint.

Can anyone give me some information on how I might shed some light on this ?

(Apologies for the very general question, I will give more specifics as I begin to understand what is actually going on!)

Comment: may be a case of url rewriting

Comment: `~` is not `root` but `home` directory.

Comment: depends on what you see as the root folder. i am willing to bet there is an api-folder somewhere in your home(!) folder

Comment: Are you using razor? In razor ~ translate into the root folder of your web application

Comment: @ATOzTOA Thank you for this...however in the entire project I cannot find a folder called 'api' ! :(

Comment: @Fox32 - Yes, this is Razor. Thanks for this information guys. I still cannot see a folder marked 'api' in the project at all! :)

Comment: You can define "routes" in asp.net mvc. They aren't real folders but asp.net understands them and call the right code. Here is an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190267/Controllers-and-Routers-in-ASP-NET-MVC-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually no need for an `api` folder. It can be a simple route configured that maps a certain URI scheme to some files. It doesn't even have to be files, it can be methods on a class.

For example, in ASP.NET Web API, you have `ApiController` classes with methods. In your case the method would be called `Function` or `GetFunction` or similar.
The route config would contain something like that:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("SomeRoute",
                    "api/{action}",                           
                    new { controller = "YourController", action = "Index" });
```

See [the introduction to routes in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) for more info.

I suggest that you also read the [entire series about the ASP.NET WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

`"~/api/function"` need not be an actual folder in your filesystem. It can be a virtual path defined in your webserver configuration, like `web.xml` in `tomcat`.